# Android Google Maps V2 Blank Screen

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

With Android 4.0.4 Google Maps API V2 shows nothing (blank white screen). **It works with Android >4.1**, so the API key is correctly configured.

There are some Warnings in Logcat, but they also occur on Android >4.1, where everything works fine.

```
01-11 16:39:03.325: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(6470): The Google Play services resources were not found. 
Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
```

Here is my project's manifest : (eclipse build target is google APIs 19)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.hska"
    android:versionCode="17"
    android:versionName="2.0.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <!-- PERMISSIONS -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <!-- Needed for GmapsApi v2 -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:name="de.hska.HsKAmpusApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/HskaTheme" >
        <provider
            android:name="de.hska.util.BuildingSuggestionProvider"
            android:authorities="de.hska.util.BuildingSuggestionProvider.search_suggestion_provider"
            android:syncable="false" />

        <!-- Activities -->
        <activity
            android:name="de.hska.gui.activity.SplashActivity"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:noHistory="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="de.hska.gui.activity.SmallScreenActivity"
            android:enabled="true" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="de.hska.gui.activity.BigScreenActivity"
            android:enabled="true" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="de.hska.gui.activity.SelectScheduleActivity"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:noHistory="false" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="de.hska.gui.activity.PersonDetailMapActivity"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_map" >
        </activity>

        <!-- Services -->
        <service
            android:name="de.hska.controller.FileService"
            android:exported="false" />
        <service android:name="de.hska.service.UpdateService" />
        <service android:name="de.hska.service.GradeService" />
        <service
            android:name="de.hska.auth.AccountAuthenticatorService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:process=":auth" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
                android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
        </service>

        <!-- Receivers -->
        <receiver
            android:name="de.hska.receiver.GradeJobScheduler"
            android:enabled="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" >
                </action>
                <action android:name="de.hska.gradeBroadcast" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="de.hska.receiver.GradeReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.extra.ALARM_COUNT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="de.hska.receiver.UpdateReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" >
                </action>
                <action android:name="de.hska.updateBroadcast" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="de.hska.receiver.ProgressReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.extra.ALARM_COUNT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <!-- Google Maps v2 API Key -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here's the google play services manifest: (eclipse build target is Google APIs level 19)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.android.gms"
    android:versionCode="4030530"
    android:versionName="4.0.30 (889083-30)" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: "The Google Play services resources were not found". Do oyu have google play services referenced. Do you test it in emulator or device.

Comment: Yes, I have referenced it and it is working both in emulator and device. But not on a 4.0.x device.